# Get Matched Value of list element from Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas

**Sample Input DF**

```
Region     Name
Europe     Project-Europe
Unknown    Project_Mexico
Unknown    Project USA
Unknown    Project
Paraguay   Project
```

**Expected DF**

```
Region     Name                   New_Region
Europe     Project_Europe         Europe
Unknown    Project_Mexico         Mexico
Unknown    Project-USA            USA
Unknown    Project                Unknown
Paraguay   Project                Paraguay
```

**Sample_List**

```
country_list= ['USA','MEXICO','Europe']
```

**Code:** **(Partially Working)**

```
pattern = '|'.join(country_list).lower()
df['New_Region'] = ariba_df['Name'].str.lower().str.contains(pattern)
```

**Problem Statement**

1. Above code makes a new column `New_Region` but gives `True` or `False`, I need the value which matched as shown in expected output.
2. The above matching should only be done when the `Region` column in Unknown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `re.I` for ignore cases with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

Last add [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set values only by boolean mask:

```
import re

country_list= ['USA','MEXICO','Europe']

pattern = '|'.join(country_list)
mask = df['Region'] == 'Unknown'

s = (df['Name'].str.extract('(' + pattern + ')', flags=re.I, expand=False)
                   .fillna('Unknown'))

df['New_Region'] = np.where(mask, s, df['Region'])
print (df)

     Region            Name New_Region
0    Europe  Project-Europe     Europe
1   Unknown  Project_Mexico     Mexico
2   Unknown     Project USA        USA
3   Unknown         Project    Unknown
4  Paraguay         Project   Paraguay
```

Comment: Sorry 1 problem, for the "Region" where the value is not unknown, it is not copying the original value, it is showing `Unknown` as the result

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Can you check now? Solution with `np.where`